# Better code for Ramsey partitions

Tags: performance-tuning, combinatorics, number-theory, partitions

Ramsey partitions for parameters $a$ and $b$ are certain integer partition of $a+b$ developed by McAvaney, Robertson, and Webb ([*Combinatorica* 1992](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01204722)) for applications in fair division problems where two players are to receive unequal shares.

They describe a test for whether a partition of $a+b$ (written in weakly decreasing order) is a Ramsey partition for $a$ and $b$: If when summing terms in the order in which they appear, leaving out whichever terms you wish, your sums do not skip over either $a$ or $b$.

So, for example, $(5,3,3,3,2,2,1,1,1)$ is not a Ramsey partition for $8$ and $13$, because $5+3+3=11$ and $5+3+3+3=14$, so 13 was skipped; or $3+3=6$ and $3+3+3 = 9$, so 8 was skipped.

For another example, $(8,5,3,3,1,1)$ is also not a Ramsey partition for $8$ and $13$ since $8+3 = 11$ and $8+3+3=14$, so 13 was skipped.  (No subsets of these parts skip 8.)

A positive example is $(8,5,3,2,1,1,1)$, which is the Ramsey partition for $8$ and $13$ with the least number of parts.  A boring Ramsey partition for $8$ and $13$ is the partition of 21 consisting of 21 parts 1.

I implemented this with the following code to find the Ramsey partitions for $a$ and $b$.  It works but is very inefficient.

```
Skips[p_] := 
 Complement[Range[Total[p]], Flatten[Map[Accumulate, Subsets[p]]]]

RP[a_, b_] := 
 Cases[IntegerPartitions[a + b], 
  p_ /; FreeQ[Map[Skips, Subsets[p]], a] && 
    FreeQ[Map[Skips, Subsets[p]], b]]
```

Tips on improving this code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Update 3:***

We get further speed-up by (1) working with the left parts of partitions with elements $\geq 2$ and appending the results with appropriate number of `1`s in the last step; and (2) making the list of candidates shorter by filtering out the ones that *skip over* `a` or `b` before performing the test on all remaining subsets:

```
rQ[targets : {__Integer}] := 
  And @@ Table[Or[Last @ # < t, MemberQ[t] @ #], {t, targets}] &;

ramseyQ2[targets : {__Integer}] := 
  AllTrue[rQ[targets] @* Accumulate] @ 
  Reverse @
  Subsets[#, {2, Length[#] - 1}] &;

SRP[{a_, a_}] := {a, a}

SRP[{a_, b_}] := Flatten[{Min[a, b], SRP[{Min[a, b], Abs[b - a]}]}, 1]

ramseyPartitions2 = 
  Module[{tl = #, t = Total @ #, m = Min @ #, l = Length @ SRP[#]}, 
    Prepend[SRP[#]] @ 
    Append[ConstantArray[1, t]]@
    Map[PadRight[#, Length@# + t - Total@#, 1] &] @
    Select[ramseyQ2[tl]] @
    Select[rQ[tl] @* Accumulate] @
    Select[Length @ # >= 1 &] @
    Map[Select[# >= 2 &]] @
    IntegerPartitions[t-1, {l, t-1}, Range @ m]] &;

rp2 = ramseyPartitions2[{8, 13}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.006318
> ```

```
rp2 == rp
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

---

**Update 2:** Complete list of Ramsey partitions:

We can cut the size of candidate partitions by half from `792` (which is `Length @ IntegerPartitions[Total[{8, 13}]]`) to `386` using

```
Length @ IntegerPartitions[Total[{8, 13}],
   {Length @ SRP[{8, 13}], Total @ {8, 13}}, 
   Range @ Min @ {8, 13}]
```

> ```
> 386
> ```

However, both numbers being small, possible speed-ups can only come from faster functions for testing  *Ramsey* property.

Three observations help to get much faster test function:

For each element `t` of the target `{a, b}`, we

1. Check only subsets of the candidate list with elements greater than 1, because *skips* cannot occur in the right tail (containg `1`s) of a candidate partition.
2. Check only subsets with length `2` to `Ceiling[t/2]`
3. Define the test function for `{a,b}` (rather than defining for a
   single integer argument, and mapping it to `a` and `b`, and combining the result with `And`) to avoid computing `Accumulate[Subsets[...]]` twice.

Using `ramseyQ` which uses these three observations, we get a 500X+ speed improvement:

```
ClearAll[ramseyQ, ramseyPartitions]


ramseyQ[targets : {__Integer}, list : {__Integer}] := 
  AllTrue[Apply[And] @ Table[MemberQ[#, t] || t > Last[#], {t, targets}] &]@
  Map[Accumulate] @
  Reverse @ 
  Subsets[Select[# >= 2 &] @ list, {2, Ceiling[Max[targets]/2]}];


ramseyPartitions[targets : {__Integer}] := 
 Module[{t = Total @ targets, m = Min @ targets, l = Length @ SRP[targets]},
   Select[ramseyQ[targets, #] &] @
   IntegerPartitions[t, {l, t}, Range @ m]]


rp = ramseyPartitions[{8, 13}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.03162
> ```

```
 Column @ rp
```

[image]

---

**Update:**  A shorter and faster alternative recursion to find the shortest Ramsey partition:

```
SRP[{a_, a_}] := {a, a}

SRP[{a_, b_}] := Flatten[{Min[a, b], SRP[{Min[a, b], Abs[b - a]}]}, 1]

SRP[{8, 13}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00004, {8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
And @@ (shortestRamseyPartition @ # == SRP [#] & /@ 
   RandomInteger[{2, 50}, {20, 2}])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

**Original answer:**

A simple implementation of the method in [McAvaney, Robertson, and Webb](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01204722) using `NestWhileList`:

```
ClearAll[step, shortestRamseyPartition]

step[{a_, b_}] := {Min[a, b], Abs[b - a]};
shortestRamseyPartition[{a_, a_}] := {a, a}

shortestRamseyPartition[{a_, b_}] := 
 Join[#, If[a + b == Total[#], {}, 
     ConstantArray[Last @ #, (a + b - Total[#]) / Last[#]]]] & @
 NestWhileList[step, {a, b}, Apply[Unequal]][[2 ;;, 1]]
```

***Examples:***

```
shortestRamseyPartition[{8, 13}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000315, {8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
shortestRamseyPartition[{17, 9}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000108, {9, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
shortestRamseyPartition[{6, 15}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000087, {6, 6, 3, 3, 3}}
> ```

Using `RamseyQ` from [lericr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291344/125) to verify:

```
RamseyQ[#, shortestRamseyPartition[#]] & /@ {{8, 13}, {6, 15}, {17, 9}}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[77];

Grid[{#, shortestRamseyPartition @ #} & /@ RandomInteger[{2, 50}, {20, 2}], 
 Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, there's a nice way to find the minimal Ramsey partition which has interesting connections to the Euclidean algorithm.  I'm more interested in the enumeration of all Ramsey partitions, e.g., efficiently testing all the partitions of 21 to find the 46 that are Ramsey partitions for 8 and 13.

Comment: @BrianHopkins, please see Update 2 for a faster enumeration.

Comment: That's a nice observation that we can skip all the partitions shorter than the shortest Ramsey partition.  In your ramseyQ, do you mean to reference lericr's RamseyQ, or is that a typo and you meant ramseyQ?  Either way, I'm having a hard time recreating your result.

Comment: @BrianHopkins, I fixed the copy/paste errors. Please try the current version.

Comment: Wonderful -- this allows me to extend Table 2 of the paper, which seems to have stopped at partitions of 27.

Comment: @BrianHopkins, a potentially much faster way is to start from the shortest partition and process it to recursively generate the full list. Something like `step[{a___, {c___, d_ /; d > 1, e : ((1) ..)}}] := Join[{a}, {c, Splice@#, e} & /@ IntegerPartitions[d]];
Rest@NestWhile[step, {{}, SRP[{8, 13}]}, Max[Last@#] > 1 &]` (This generates 31 of the 46 partitions; with an appropriate specification of `step` it should be possible to get the full list).

Comment: Interesting idea; it reminds me of Brylawski's operations related to the dominance partial order on partitions.  Maybe instead of restricting to partitions with at least SRP's number of parts, it would be better to look at all partitions lower than the SRP and screen those for Ramseyness, as you called it.

Comment: Follow-up to my last comment: (8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1), the minimal Ramsey partition for 8 & 13, dominates 371 partitions of 21, compared to the 386 found by the (easier to compute) length restriction, so not very promising.

Answer (score 6):

This implementation is faster than yours, but probably not optimal. Given how fast IntegerPartitions grows, I'm not optimistic that anything will be acceptably performant for anything but small integers.

```
RamseyQ[target_Integer, list : {___Integer}] :=
  AllTrue[Accumulate /@ Rest[Subsets[list]], MemberQ[#, target] || target > Last[#] &];
RamseyQ[targets : {__Integer}, list_] :=
  And @@ (RamseyQ[#, list] & /@ targets);
RamseyPartitions[targets : {__Integer}] :=
  Select[IntegerPartitions[Total[targets]], RamseyQ[targets, #] &]
```

The following took about 30 seconds and found 46 RamseyPartitions. I don't know the correct result without checking them all by hand, so I haven't proven that this implementation is correct.

```
RamseyPartitions[{8, 13}]
```

I did check my implementation against yours for smaller integers, and the results agreed.

Comment: There are, in fact, 46 Ramsey partitions for 8 & 13 (the authors list them).